# How to buy bitcoins with Dwolla now 6/14/13?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, dwolla

Since Bitinstant has deactivated dwolla deposits and campbx has a 31 day wait, besides otc, is there any other exchange ??  Maybe a foreign exchange ?

thx

Comment: People who vote to close: If you're the first one, please write a comment to the user so that he/she can understand what is wrong about it. Especially if the user is new. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to buy at localbitcoins.com if you are comfortable dealing with strangers. May be use escrow.

https://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/usd/dwolla/